# How to fork/mirror my openshift application source code to a github repo

Tags: wordpress, openshift

i have created an open shift wordpress application some times back and i have really a pretty much amount of data in it. I just want to pull the whole source into my github so that i can work on few weird part. Is it possible now to download the source code? i googled and got no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check this info on the Openshift Forum - https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-keep-a-github-repository-and-an-openshift-repository-in-sync

Add your GitHub repo as another remote and push to there.